# Detect when Webclient.DownloadFileAsync hangs because of change in dynamic Ip Address

Tags: c#, winforms, download, ip, webclient

I am using webclient for large size file download.

In my country, every 12 hours, the Ip Changes, so if user is downloading file and his ipChanges , the download hangs, but I get not feedback that it hanged..

I would like to detect this in windows form , c#.

```
public void DownloadFile(string urlAddress, string location)
{
    try
    {
        // The stopwatch which we will be using to calculate the download speed
        using (webClient = new WebClient())
        {                 
            webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);
            webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);

            // The variable that will be holding the url address (making sure it starts with http://)
            Uri URL = urlAddress.StartsWith("http://", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ? new Uri(urlAddress) : new Uri("http://" + urlAddress);

            // Start the stopwatch which we will be using to calculate the download speed
            sw.Start();

            // Start downloading the file
            webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(urlAddress), location);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

I also tried calling this for detecting Ip Address change but it is not being fired when manually resetting router.

```
public Form1()
{ 
    NetworkChange.NetworkAddressChanged += new NetworkAddressChangedEventHandler(AddressChangedCallback);
}

private void AddressChangedCallback(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Code here...
}
```

Comment: As a whole your PC would not necessarily be aware of a router changing IP. as its own IP hasnt changed, nor necessarily dropped as the router unless power cycled keeps contact with it

Comment: Dumb workaround: do you know in advance what time the change'll happen?

Comment: thank you for your answer, this is for use in machines all over the country , every house or company has its own time for the ip to change since the count starts from the last time your ip changed (reset the router etc)

Comment: Does the *machine* have its IP changed or the *router* it's connected to? This is important, because if the machine IP itself does not change but the router's does, then your router is broken, since the connection should either reset or be transparently carried forward. The proper workaround from the client side would be to detect if no data has been transmitted in X seconds and abort the download; unfortunately `WebClient` has no facilities for that, but [`HttpWebRequest` does](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.readwritetimeout).

Comment: Thank you for your answer Jeroen Mostert, the  IP Address is on the router, the machine can not see the IP,

About the HttpWebRequest your mentioned, is it possible to continue the download onced it has been hanged because the ip address changed?

Comment: If the server supports it (most do), then yes, by checking how much you have and using [`HttpWebRequest.AddRange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/4ds43y3w) on subsequent requests. [`wget`](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) offers this stuff out of the box (retries, restarts, the lot) but is of course a separate application.